# ansible apt update not working because of undefined value

Tags: ansible

When I try to run my Play with the following content:

Call from my tasks/main.yml

```
- name: Special System Settings
  block:

  - name: Kali Setup
    import_tasks: Kali/kali.yml
    when: ansible.distribution == "Kali"
```

First Block in my kali.yml

```
- name: First Run Client Setup
  block:
    - name: check if updates are needed
      become: yes
      apt:
        update_cache: yes
        cache_valid_time: 3600
        upgrade: dist
        autoclean: yes

    - name: Request newest version
      uri:
        url: "{{ appimage.dl_url }}"
        follow_redirects: none
      register: url_appimage
      failed_when: no

    - name: Check if already exists
      stat:
        path: "{{ appimage.appimage_dir }}/{{ url_appimage.location|basename }}"
      register: download_appimage_local

    - name: Download and place
      get_url:
        url: "{{ url_appimage.location }}"
        dest: "{{ appimage.appimage_dir }}/{{ url_appimage.location|basename }}"
      when: not download_appimage_local.stat.exists
  tags: always
```

I receive the following error:

```
TASK [os : check if updates are needed] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check 'ansible.distribution == \"Kali\"' failed. The error was: error while evaluating conditional (ansible.distribution == \"Kali\"): 'ansible' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/test/ansible/os/tasks/Kali/kali.yml': line 5, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  block:\n    - name: check if updates are needed\n      ^ here\n"}
```

I dont understand why it hangs up because of a value I never defined in the whole yaml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First make sure you have [`gather_facts`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/gather_facts_module.html) set to true.

And the variable that holds the dist is named `ansible_distribution`, not with a `.`. See [this](https://ansible-tips-and-tricks.readthedocs.io/en/latest/os-dependent-tasks/variables/).

```
  - name: Kali Setup
    import_tasks: Kali/kali.yml
    when: ansible_distribution == "Kali"
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you!